# When are elements ordered in PriorityQueues?

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

Does the PriorityQueue class inserts the elements priority wise or it's just that when we poll the element only then it finds out the highest priority element and returns it?

Comment: The elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering, or by a Comparator provided at queue construction time, depending on which constructor is used.

Comment: Have a look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java)

Comment: But then I could see a method "siftDownUsingComparator()" being called from inside poll() method. What is that for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the source code of JDK itself(formatting mine):

The Priority queue represented as a balanced binary heap: the two children of `queue[n]` are `queue[2*n+1]` and `queue[2*(n+1)]`.

The priority queue is ordered by the `comparator`, or by the elements' *natural ordering*, if the *comparator is null*: For each node `n` in the heap and each descendant `d` of `n`, `n <= d`.  The element with the lowest value is in `queue[0]`, assuming the queue is non-empty.

So, you can consider the insertion/deletion of elements in PriorityQueue as operations providing results along with the balancing of the heap.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, the `PriorityQueue` classes internally maintains a [binary heap](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Binary%20Heaps/heaps.html), and the ordering of items in that heap is determined by either the default ordering, or by a Comparator. The binary heap is maintained in a list.

Your question asks when elements are ordered. When you add an item to the queue or remove an item from the queue, the order of items is rearranged so that the highest priority item is at the top of the heap: at index 0 in the list. So the answer to your main question is that `PriorityQueue` *always* knows which is the highest-priority item. That makes the `peek()` function very efficient.

The order of items in the rest of the list is a little more involved. The rest of the list is *ordered*, but not necessarily *sorted*. The ordering is such that rearranging the heap after insertion or removal is efficient. See the above-linked article on binary heaps for the details about heap ordering.